# What does AUTOMATIC setting in LocalSearchMetaheuristic on ortools do?

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools

I've been working with OR-Tools and I've been using the default parameters so far. It is working correctly most of the times with different scenarios. However sometimes the computation never stops. I've set the `time_limit_ms` parameter and I saw that, by default, `LocalSearchMetaheuristic` is set to `AUTOMATIC`. What does that mean? How is the `LocalSearchMetaheuristic` chosen? Is it always `GREEDY_DESCENT` since I don't set `time_limit_ms`?

I've already tried to google it but I haven't found any documentation or code where this function/parameter is declared.

Comment: I've found the definition of `FirstSolutionStrategy` [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_enums.proto), unfortunately not `AUTOMATIC` yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the code [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.cc) in the `SetupMetaheuristics` method.

Basically the `AUTOMATIC` setup is not as smart as I thought. It is a vanilla greedy descent search.